# Replace a substring in an HTML formatted string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace a substring in a HTML string and averything before that substring.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$str = "
<font color=#6111cc>00820: </font>1: Line1
<font color=#6111cc>00821: </font>2: Line2
<font color=#6111cc>00822: </font>3: Line3
<font color=#6111cc>00823: </font>4: Line4
<font color=#6111cc>00824: </font>5: Line5
<font style=\"color:green\"><b><font color=#6111cc>00882: </font>6: No:6 check</b></font>
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check1
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check2
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check3
";
$replace = "<font style=\"color:green\"><b><font color=#6111cc>00882: </font>6: No:6 check</b></font>";

$str =~ s/(.*)\Q$replace\E//;

print "str: $str\n";
```

I need to replace the following substring and everything before:

```
<font style=\"color:green\"><b><font color=#6111cc>00882: </font>6: No:6 check</b></font>
```

The result I need is:

```
str = "<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check1
       <font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check2
       <font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check3";
```

The code I have tryed does't work, it replace only the key line, and not everything before that line. Output:

```
<font color=#6111cc>00820: </font>1: Line1
<font color=#6111cc>00821: </font>2: Line2
<font color=#6111cc>00822: </font>3: Line3
<font color=#6111cc>00823: </font>4: Line4
<font color=#6111cc>00824: </font>5: Line5

<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check1
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check2
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check3
```

Comment: I use the "s": $str =~ s/(.*)\Q$replace\E//; This doesn't work because of the special characters from the html lines: "/".

Comment: You appear to be trying to parse and modify HTML using regular expressions. Since HTML is not a regular language, this is likely to bite you in the future. Have you considered using a real parser from CPAN, such as Mojo::DOM or one of the HTML::Parser family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close; you need the 'treat newlines as regular characters' single-line modifier, `s`:

```
$str =~ s/(.*)\Q$replace\E//s;
```

See: Perl [regex modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) — or `perldoc perlre`.

(The newline at the start of the output value is the newline after the text to be matched. I had to think about that for a few seconds.)

It is a good idea (though it is not material to your problem) to use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in all your Perl scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code deletes everything *on the same line* up to and including the contents of `$replace` because `.` matches everything *except newlines*.

If you mean to delete lines 1 to 5 as well then you need to use the `/s` modifier on your subtitution, which changes `.` to match any character at all.

You should also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` (instead of the `-w` command-line option) at the top of every Perl program.

Using single quotes removes the need to escape double quotes.

This is what your code should look like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<'__END_HTML__';
<font color=#6111cc>00820: </font>1: Line1
<font color=#6111cc>00821: </font>2: Line2
<font color=#6111cc>00822: </font>3: Line3
<font color=#6111cc>00823: </font>4: Line4
<font color=#6111cc>00824: </font>5: Line5
<font style="color:green"><b><font color=#6111cc>00882: </font>6: No:6 check</b></font>
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check1
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check2
<font color=#6600cc>00883: </font>1: Check3
__END_HTML__

my $replace = '<font style="color:green"><b><font color=#6111cc>00882: </font>6: No:6 check</b></font>';

$str =~ s/(.*)\Q$replace\E//s;

print "str: $str\n";
```